# How to check the list of events bound to an element by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-events

I'm looking for a way to list all events added to a certain element by Javascript. I know `getEventListeners` is available in dev tools, but it is not available in script.

I know with jQuery, I can check events with the below code. However, as this is a private method, it can only list events added by jQuery.

```
$._data(element, 'events')
```

I also checked this page, but this method needs to be executed before events are added.
https://www.sqlpac.com/en/documents/javascript-listing-active-event-listeners.html

After all, is there no general way to check if an element has events after those events are added?

Comment: I do not believe there is a vanilla way of doing this. Is there a specific purpose for this code that you have in mind? I can really only think of debugging as far as this being useful, and as you've said the browser devtools give us that capability.

Comment: I need to do this to make a bookmarklet for analyzing other websites.